# Why my ajax file uploader does not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, file-upload

I'm trying to create a ajax file upload module. Please look at the following code snippet,

```
//create the form for uploading the file the ajax file
FileUploader.prototype.createForm = function() {
    // create the new form
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.id = this.form_id;
    form.action = this.url;
    form.method = 'post';
    form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
    form.target = 'file_upload_iframe';

    // try to create a file type of input failed at [1]
    /* var input_file = document.createElement('input');
    input_file.type = 'file';
    input_file.name = this.name;
    input_file.value = this.file;  [1] */

    // try to clone the input file but failed to insert it to the old form[2] 
    // or the new form [3] either
    var input_file = document.getElementById('userfile');
    var new_input_file = document.cloneNode(true);
    // document.getElementById('file_upload').appendChild(new_input_file); [2]
    new_input_file.id = ''; 

    form.appendChild(new_input_file); // [3]
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    return form;
};
```

1. Why at the place [1] I have get a security error `Security error" code: "1000`, could you give a reference source?
2. Why I could not append the new_input_file into the new created form[3] or even append the new cloned new_input_file into the old form([2])?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to clone the whole document, it makes little sense. What you need is such code:

```
var new_input_file = input_file.cloneNode(true);
```

Anyhow, the `value` of input type file is read only for obvious security reasons so the only way to "overcome" this is adding the actual input to the new form:

```
form.appendChild(input_file);
```

And the file should be preserved. (Didn't test it)

Comment: Thanks. Oh, I should recheck the code, actually I thought it was **input_file** but not document and invest half an hour to find the non-exist answer.

Comment: After setting in front of my notebook for nearly 8 hours....My head is messed up... : )

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use jquery to manipulate the DOM ?

```
var input = $('<input>'); // create your element
input.append($('#userfile').clone()); // append something
```